# Ionic 4 - diccionario con api Words API

Tags: ionic4

Tengo un problema en mi código que que me arroja el siguiente error:

> Property 'results' does not exist on type

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {  WordService } from '../services/word.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

  myWord:string;
  myWordDef:string;

 constructor(private wordService: WordService){
  }

  getWordDef(){
    console.log(this.myWord);
    this.wordService.getWordDef(this.myWord)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.results[0].definition);
      this.myWordDef=response.results[0].definition;   
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.warn(err);
    });;

  }

}
```

por favor si me pueden ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Se refiere a que la respuesta que estas recibiendo por parte de la promesa no contiene dichos datos.

Trata de ver en consola la respuesta como tal que te manda dicha promesa como esta en tu codigo `console.log(response);` y despues de eso revisa si efectivamente la pripiedad de `results` es un arreglo, Ademas de eso tambien podrias indicarle el tipo de dato que es la respuesta, si no estas seguro de saber cual es o no tienes una interface o clase para definirlo simplemente podrias hacer lo siguiente.

```
this.wordService.getWordDef(this.myWord)
  .then((response: any) => {})
```

Al agregar any ya le estarias dando un tipo de dato y no te devolveria errores por ese lado.